# Current Location in background Service in android does not work

Tags: java, android, gps, location, background-service

The code below does not work when the application is minimized or closed and doesn't return the current location.

For example, locationCallback only works once and does not work  after the app is minimized.
It should be noted that this service has been added to the manifest. It works in the video that I saw on YouTube  [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_RK_5bCoOY)

```
public class UpdateLocationService extends Service {
 
static final int LOCATION_SERVICE_id = 175;
static final String ACTION_START_LOCATION_SERVICE = "startLocationService";
static final String ACTION_STOP_LOCATION_SERVICE = "stopLocationService";
private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

        if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
            double lat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
            double lng = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
            Log.d(TAG, lat + ", " + lng);

        }
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startLocationService() {
    

    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
    }
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());

    startForeground(LOCATION_SERVICE_id, builder.build());


}


private void stopLocationService() {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null)
         if (action.equals(ACTION_START_LOCATION_SERVICE)){
             startLocationService();
         }else if (action.equals(ACTION_STOP_LOCATION_SERVICE)){
             stopLocationService();
         }
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

}

Comment: At the very least you'll need to request the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission on API 29 and higher.

Comment: This permission is in the my manifest

Comment: It's not enough to just have it in the manifest, you also need to request the permission at runtime.

Comment: i check  permission in service  with this condition but it does not works  again  and returned true.
 if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

Comment: Use this in your activity class to request the permissions:
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);`

Comment: I do this and I got the necessary permissions

Comment: If you use a service, you will likely need to use a ForegroundService: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: tnx dude, solved with append    android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" and
 android:foregroundServiceType="location" to service in manifest

Answer (score 0):

Starting background service has been restricted after Android O https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background. If you still what to get a location in the background, please consider WorkManger and Foreground services